# For professional designing company, what is the key to design an app elegantly?

Tags: design

I am coding and found it's pretty hard to come up with an elegant design for my app at the  first attempt.

- First time I'm only about 40% happy, then I refactor it to code the same app a second time (almost start from scratch).
- Second time coding, I'm only happy about 60% happy, so I refactor it once more to code the same app a third time (not start from scratch but I made a lot of changes).
- Third time coding, I'm only happy about 80%. Here I am quite happy but I think if I can start over I can do much better and it should be very solid. But I am running out of time now. So I just leave it like it is. 80% Happy.

So my key word is "**to keep re-factoring**".

But this is my point of view as an indie developer so I don't know how a design company would design an application.

Suppose I give my idea to a professional designing company, will they keep refactoring like that many times to achieve an elegant design?

Or because they are a big design company, are they able to design everything well at the first attempt?

Do you work for a software design company? If you do then how does the professional designing company design applications elegantly?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491 This site is [about] questions, not polls

Comment: Software is never ready. It is simply good enough.

Comment: @Juha so u work for a software designing company? how they design software for customers?

Comment: Depends on the methodology (RUP or agile), but in general: 1) Gather requirements (use cases, user stories), 2) Add them to change management software (RUP), or divide the stories into tasks and assign them to workers, 3) Do the work, 4) Commit the updates for peer review and architect review (RUP), or just peer review (agile), 5) Add them to the main development build for others, 6) Build it, and roll it out on set intervals, or when sprint is ready, 7) Get user feedback, 8) Restart from point 1

Comment: "Restart from point 1" so ur company sometimes are not happy with the final product so they has to start over from step 1? How often do they have to start over?

Comment: @Kiti I think Juha means they have an iterative process, not that they do a full redesign.

Comment: Yes, especially in agile you will change things around fairly often, based on user comments and requests. The earlier in the design process you are, the more often it happens. Usually later on most things settle down (= less changes to old/existing things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you can get to a usable working solution in only 3 iterations, you're doing well.**

The number of iterations and the amount of refactoring per iteration is highly dependent on the nature of the problem, how well you understand the specifications, how well the end customer knows what they want, and so on.

Some companies will iterate a lot more than 3 times.  Few if any will do it in less (unless we're talking about trivial programs).

With practice you'll find the process easier.

As for big design companies, it's important to remember that they have more people to work on a program and some of them might have more experience.  However, that doesn't necessarily make them smarter or "better" (however you define that term) than you.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: if you have enough customers after 3 iterations so you get paid for many more iterations, *then* you're doing well.

Comment: so u mean even big design company won't sure they doing right at the 1st time. ex, Microsoft design terribly Win vista and they have to throw it away so they waste lot of resource for doing wrongly right?

Comment: That's pretty much it.  However, don't try to compare yourself to Microsoft until you have as many developers as they do and as big a budget.  They operate in a completely different environment than you or I do.  It's true they can do things we can't, but they also face problems we don't.